# How do I map SQL server login to user in database snapshot(read-only)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to map SQL Server login to the user in snapshot-database (original database is on another server). I am getting the following error:

> Failed to update database because the database is read-only (Error: 3906).

The same login and user exist on another server, but user in snapshot-database is user without a login.

How can I solve this problem?

Kind regards

Comment: You can't `ALTER` a `USER` if the database is in read only mode. To `ALTER` the `USER` you must first make the database not be in read only mode. Otherwise you'll need to create a `LOGIN` on the host which has the same SID as the `USER` you want to map it to.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for your response. I have created Login with the same SID and it worked.